# Confidence Intervals for ICC

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, intraclass-correlation

I was wondering if anyone might know of a way to calculate confidence intervals around an ICC(1) value? I'm running a multilevel model using the lmer() function in lme4 where I'm interested in seeing if there is a significant amount of within-person variation in a particular construct. I've run a null model for the variable and calculated the ICC and residual ICC but I was hoping to get a confidence interval around the ICC (and subtract this from 1 to get the confidence interval for the residual ICC) to see if it includes 0. However, I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this yet.

Comment: There are lots of papers each for slightly different contexts, e.g., https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24535554/.

Comment: Apart from methods specifically tailored for this problem, there are the general purpose methods for generating confidence intervals: *bootstrap* and *jackknife*.